# using for on objects and their properties?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

i'm writing a program in C# , which contains a dozen toolstrips and each one contains a toolstriplabel :

toolstriplabel1
toolstriplabel2
toolstriplabel3
        .
        .
        .
toolstriplabel11
toolstriplabel12

i want to change each ones text with a "for" loop , how can i do that??
i can use "if" with other variables to meet this , but i want to avoid the dozen "if"s i have to write.
How Can i use a "for" loop with toolstriplabel's , text property?
i tried using this code , it doesn't work :

```
    for (int r = 0; r < NumGraphs; r++)
    { 
       toolStripLabel+"i".text=...
    }
```

Comment: And this happens to be which language? JS?

Comment: yup, forgot that , sorry , C#

Comment: yes it is windows Forms

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try something like this,

```
        foreach (Control ctr in this.Controls)
        {
            if (ctr is ToolStripLabel)
            {
              // ur code
            }
        }
```

Comment: I find using of `var label = ctr as ToolStripLabel;` followed by `if (ctr != null) { ... }` more pleasant. Instead of asking on a type I directly cast to the type, because you will need to do it later anyway.

Comment: this would work if i wanted to apply a single value to all of them not if i want them to be specified each seperately

Comment: @Hitman2847 It's probably caused by asking the question the wrong way. Now I see that you are asking how to change their text without a bunch of if statements, but it actually seems like you are just having troubles with looping through them. You should express your question better so that it's clear what are all the problems you need to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with C# but You can create an array of these toolStrips. In `for` loop, set the `text` property of the `i`th element in the array at `i`th iteration.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < NumGraphs; i++) { 
         toolStripLabel[i].text="YOUR TEXT";
  }
```

Comment: well that's easy but it didn't come to my mind ,thanks , but that also requires all 12 elements declare seperately , isn't there any way using for directly on the object?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with C#.

Comment: thanx anyway , at least i know how to do it indirectly

Answer (score 0):

What about using LINQ on collection of controls?

```
var labels = this.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                 .OfType<ToolStripLabel>()
                 .Where(l => l.Name.Contains("toolstriplabel"));
```

Then you can simply loop through them with a foreach loop.

```
foreach (var label in labels) { label.Text = ""; }
```